# Query all collection names

Tags: ravendb

Is there a way to query all the collection names? I figured there must be a relatively straight-forward way since Raven Studio is already doing it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `GetTermsAsync`.

Using example:

```
DatabaseCommands.GetTermsAsync("Raven/DocumentsByEntityName", "Tag", "", 100)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Let me verify this tonight.